# How to extract a subimage using PixelReader and JavaFX?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I have a .png image, and I want to extract one part of that image using the PixelReader class, and rebuild it as an image :

```
Image image = new Image("file:ressources/spritesheets/Zelda_Overworld.png");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
PixelReader pr = image.getPixelReader();
pr.getPixels(0, 0, 16, 16, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), buffer, 0, 64);
Image tile = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
```

I can display *image* and *buffer* seems to contain values, but I can't display *tile*, tile.getPixelReader() returns null, tile.getWidth() and tile.getHeight() return 0.0.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let [`WritableImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) do this for you:

```
Image image = new Image("file:ressources/spritesheets/Zelda_Overworld.png");
Image tile = new WritableImage(image.getPixelReader(), x, y, width, height);
```

Depending on the use of `tile` doing this may not be necessary at all. `ImageView` has a [`viewport` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) that allows you to choose the part of the image to display and `GraphicsContext` provides an overloaded version of the `drawImage` method to draw a part of the image to the `Canvas`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why the other solution didn't work, but yours is simpler and works perfectly.
I use tiles to build some maps, so I directly use images to make the final display, but your solution to just display tiles directly from the spritesheet looks quite interesting!